# Returning a table from stored procedure as a full result set (then passing it to script task as object)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a procedure that returns a table (name "ValidationResultTbl"):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CM_ValidateInput @FileName VARCHAR(250)AS
DECLARE @ValidationResultTbl TABLE (ValidationDescription VARCHAR(100), ErrCnt INT)
DECLARE @ErrCounter INT

BEGIN

--some irrelevant code

IF @ErrCounter > 0
    INSERT INTO @ValidationResultTbl
    VALUES ('Errors were found in the file''s mapping', @ErrCounter)

SELECT * FROM @ValidationResultTbl
END
GO
```

I'm executing the stored procedure in SSIS using an sql-task:
[image]

In Result Set tab I set the variable that receives the result as ValidationResult (type object):

[image]

I then add a script task that is supposed to concatenate the values of the first column of ValidationResult table:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
public void Main()
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::ValidationResult"].Value);
            String msg = "";
            String msg1 = "";
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Object[] array = row.ItemArray;
                msg = array[0].ToString();
                msg1 += msg + "\n";
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

(The task script editor:)
[image]

It doesn't work as expected, and when I debug I see that the object that is supposed to hold the table is actually empty.

I've tried changing the procedure to return a single string row, then used it in the script task and didn't have a problem so I'm assuming the problem has something to do with the SQL task not retrieving the table properly or not passing it to the Script task properly.

Comment: (The ValidationResult table is passed as a ReadWriteVariable for later needs.)

Comment: You can extend the SP to simply do the concatenation in the SP. Also make sure you put `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your SP (after the `BEGIN`)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Nice workaround, but there is another column in this table that I would need to use later so I can't just return a string.

Comment: By looking at your `script task` code - you are assigning your first column to `msg`, but can't seem to find where you are doing the concatenation and what is purpose of `id` and `msg1` here, is this your complete code?

Comment: @Abhishek - There was a mistake, `msg` was originally called id and I've changed it in my question to make the code clearer but forgot to change it there.

Comment: You can return two columns and still avoid a script task

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - How so? I need to display the final string in a message box.
Also, I think the problem has to do with how the script task handles the returned object, so even if I would have found a way to avoid the script task the returned table would possibly still be unusable.

Comment: Your existing sample script doesn't do that. Anyway - yes if you want to display a messagebox you need script. There is no practical use for this in a real world SSIS package though. Anyway at least put `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your proc. That may help

Comment: I just tried to replicate your use-case and all worked well for me. Have you tried changing your `stored procedure` to select from a table instead of table variable

Comment: @Abhishek - For some reason that did the trick! Bravo.
Any idea why though?

Comment: To dug deep have to look at your `Transaction` scope. Could be due to the variable scope and db connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue but for SSIS (depending on version of SQL server) has issue sgrabbing the result set from temp tables or table variables, in your script task you need to do something like this to identify the columns and types of data returned:

```
EXEC SP_CM_ValidateInput 
WITH RESULT SETS
(
 ( 
  ValidationDescription VARCHAR(100), 
  ErrCnt INT
 ) 
) 
GO
```

Details on WITH RESULT SET:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/